# URLConnection setRequestProperty "Range" Header getting HTTP 416? Curl works

Tags: java, android

I need to use the "Range" header to continue downloading a partially downloaded file with my android app.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + this.downloadedBytes + "-");
```

And when I log it to logcat I see only what I've

```
conn.getRequestProperties().toString()
{Range=[bytes=3129-]}
```

My server is responding with a HTTP 416, range cannot be satisfied. I see this response in the apache access log. I get an IOException (java.io.FileNotFoundException), which is my guess as to how it deals with a 416, just like it would a 404. And that is a totally normal response, except that curl works perfectly to that same file!

```
curl -I --header "Range: bytes=3129-` ...
```

I get the expected HTTP 200 response:

```
Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 15:26:59 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1915
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 19:17:33 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Range: bytes 3129-5043/5044
Content-Type: text/html
```

What am I missing on the android/java side here? What about the request is making apache serve back a 416 when curl works just fine?